# How to write test classes for Continuation Controller (using Async WSDL class)

Tags: apex, unit-test, continuation, asynchronous-testing

I have implemented `Continuation` concept with the Asynchronous WSDL class, in a controller of page. So, I facing difficulties while writing test classes for the same.

For my requirement I have generated(from WSDL file) WSDL classes(one for Synchronous and other class for Async) and I am using generated AsyncWSDL class in my implementation. My webservice method will return an instance of a class generated inside the WSDL class. And there is some code inside generated WSDL classes to parse the response.

For the synchronous webservice callout test classes, we have to use `Test.setMock()` and we can return the desired object as response.

For Async with Continuation, I know that we have to set the test response with `Test.setContinuationResponse()` and use `Test.invokeContinuationMethod()` to call the callback method.
Here the `setContinuationResponse()` method signature is `setContinuationResponse(String requestLabel, System.HttpResponse mockResponse)`, and `HttpResponse.SetBody()` will accept String as parameter. But I want to return an object(instance of a inner class of WSDL class) as response, which will be actually returned by `WebServiceCalloutFuture.getValue()` method of Future instance in Async WSDL classes. If I generate desired class instance and pass the `classInstance.toString()` to `setBody()`, then I am getting error at the `WebServiceCalloutFuture.getValue()` method inside Async WSDL class.

Is there any way to set the desired Class instance as response to my continuation call response?
Please assist on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find the exact answer for my question, I have achieved what I wanted to do with a small workaround. 
My goal is to test the Asynchronous WSDL Callout made with Continuation. As I have explained in the question, generally my generated asynchronous WSDL class method returns an object as the callout response.

So, I have amended AsyncWSDL class getValue() method to return the object with dummy values, if running in the test context. This is working fine, and able to cover the code.